# CasperJS PHP - Caper Script Run Command Failing

Tags: php, casperjs

I have installed CasperJS wrapper for PHP along with all the required requisites. The package is here:

[PHP CasperJS](https://github.com/alwex/php-casperjs)

I am trying to run the basic script example provided on the github readme page, but I am getting the below error:

```
Notice: tempnam(): file created in the system's temporary directory in C:\wamp64\www\casper2\vendor\phpcasperjs\phpcasperjs\src\Casper.php on line 595
```

After troubleshooting the script, the issue is with this line of Code:

```
$casper ->run();
```

Additional information:

1. Using php 7
2. Running WAMP server on my localhost

Comment: Hello! Is there anything else below the "Notice: tempnam()" message?

Comment: Yes, 3 items in the call stack: 1) {main}( ) - line 0; 2) Browser\Casper->run( ) - line 71; 3) tempnam ( ) - line 595, casper.php

Comment: I am not really sure what the problem is... But I think that there are a few nice things to try:
1 - Add this to the beginning of you php file.

putenv("PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE=/usr/local/bin/phantomjs");
putenv("DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH");

2 - Have a look here: https://php.net/manual/en/ini.sect.safe-mode.php#ini.safe-mode-exec-dir

Comment: Problem solved. Will post solution as the answer...

Comment: Nice! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

When declaring the Casper object, you need to explicitly declare the location of the CasperJS executable.

The problematic line of code is this:

$casper = new Casper();

The correct code is this:

```
$casper = new Casper(__DIR__ . "/location-of-casperjs”, __DIR__ . "/location-of-tempfolder”);
```

A side note, the second parameter seems to be ignored, by default the location appears to go back to c:\tmp - still trying to figure out how to override this.